# Confusion between equations of kinetic energy and mass-energy equivalence

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, thermal-radiation, mass-energy

The present mass of the Sun is $2.0 \times 10^{30} \mathrm{~kg} .$ The Sun emits radiation at an average rate of $3.8 \times 10^{26} \mathrm{Js}^{-1}$. Calculate the time in years for the mass of the Sun to decrease by one millionth of its present mass. $1y=3.2 \times 10^{7} \mathrm{~s}$

*My incorrect solution*:

\begin{array}{l}
P=\frac{W}{t} \Rightarrow t=\frac{W}{P} \\
\text { One millionth of the sun’s present mass is } 2 \times 10^{24} kg \\
\therefore t=\frac{\frac{m v^{2}}{2}}{P} \\
=\frac{\frac{2 \times 10^{24} \times\left(3 \times 10^{8}\right)^{2}}{2}}{3.8 \times 10^{26}} \\
=2.36 . . \times 10^{14} \mathrm{~s} \\
=7.4 \times 10^{6} \mathrm{years} \text { to } 2 \mathrm{sf}
\end{array}

Why can’t the equation for kinetic energy be used in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used
$$KE=\frac{1}{2}mc^2$$
which is incorrect! Besides, it's in no way correct. Classically, it seems to be the kinetic energy of the particle with the speed of light which is not possible.

---

You have to use the Einstein mass-energy equation that is
$$E=mc^2$$
From this you can find, How mass should be reduced so that the sun can provide the power it provides. And then How much time required for Sun's mass reduce by the given amount.